# How to pick meaningful samples from a huge population

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis, sampling

I am new to the forum. This is in regards to my analytics project for my PG.

I have my data set consisting of 87656 rows and 52 columns. The data is arranged in a sequence of dates. Out of this huge sample,  I have to PICK up a meaningful SAMPLE for some study.

With the help of some equations, I have gathered the NUMBER of samples that i can collect to consider it a sample- turns out to be around 13000 with 99% confidence level.

The challenge now for me is HOW do i pick those 13000 rows?
Please help.

Comment: If you don't have any specific information, just pick 13000 random samples. In order to validate your choice, pick another 13000 random samples and then compare study results

Comment: Can you please help with any python code how do i pick up those 13000 random samples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the comment: "How do I pick up those 13000 random samples". Example is taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-n-elements-from-list-in-python/

I checked that it works for me.

```
cat random_sample.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
# importing random module
import random
  
# declaring list
list = [2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8]
  
# initializing the value of n
n = 4
  
# printing n elements from list
print(random.sample(list, n))
```

Running the example:

```
random_sample.py
[4, 2, 6, 8]
```

My environment:

```
uname -rsvi
Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.5
```